# Im stuggling using aria2c commands

Tags: linux, wget, aria2

Im trying to download dataset from [here](https://physionet.org/content/mimic3wdb-matched/1.0/)

Since it's very large to download (2.4T), so I tried use `aria2c` instead of `wget`.

There is `wget` command line `wget -r -N -c -np https://physionet.org/files/mimic3wdb-matched/1.0/`.

Of coure it worked well, but it's slow.

Thus I tried `aria2c https://physionet.org/files/mimic3wdb-matched/1.0/` and with flags `aria2c -c -j 4 -x 4 -s 4 -k 1M -m 0 --allow-overwrite=true --auto-file-renaming=false https://physionet.org/files/mimic3wdb-matched/1.0/`

Those command only download one html file which is the page of `https://physionet.org/files/mimic3wdb-matched/1.0/`  : index.html

Could someone help me?
Thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

As seen is this [question](https://github.com/aria2/aria2/issues/822) aria2c is not able to parse itself the content of a folder.

You'll need either to parse the folder by another mean and give the result to aria2c or, if there is a constant pattern and you know it, you can generate a list of files with the `-P` [argument](http://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#cmdoption-P).